# Is It possible to add image on border?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

All I hope you doing good. I want to add image on border.
Consider a border with 100px solid. I just want to put the image on border Is It possible with CSS. Like I used positions, z-index but couldn't see effect. you can see the code. I just want to show image on the border not back the border.
Example https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIUNl.jpg

```html
<img width="30%" height="30%" src="https://i.imgur.com/deoFQ7i.png" />
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; max-width: 600px !important; border-left: 62px solid #fca9cf;">
    <tr class="container" style="">
        <td valign="top" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/deoFQ7i.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: -20px; background-size: contain; border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnTextBlock" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" width="100%"
                            class="mcnTextContentContainer">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 0px 18px 9px; line-height: 200%; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #603813; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 16px; text-align: left;">
                                            <p style="                          font-family: philosopher;color: #603813;font-size: 24px;text-align: center;line-height: 200%;margin: 10px 0;padding: 0;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @G-Cyrillus No, My question is how we can add image "ON" the border not around the border.

Comment: this may helps you https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image2

Comment: @RayeesAC You couldn't understood the question

Comment: @TimB.McKinnon do you have any example of this working somewhere? or an image/screenshot? thank you

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/1IA2Ddj.jpg

Comment: `position: absolute` is your friend, oh yes, and `z-index`

Comment: Looks like you're using the term "border" incorrectly. In CSS it means [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

```css
.rectangle {
  background:pink;
  width:100px;height:150px;
  position:relative;
}

img {
  width:100px;position:absolute;
  right:-86px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/deoFQ7i.png">
</div>
```

Comment: This is just a demo to help you understand better how it works and has to be adapted to your code.